# Can't uninstall dash to dock

Tags: 20.04, dock, dash-to-dock

I'm a newbie to ubuntu and was trying to uninstall dash to dock as I don't need it. I uninstalled it using `sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` and the dock still showed up in activities overview. Then I found someone used to `sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` to resolve the issue. I tried, still no luck. And now this big dock shows up in activities overview.[image: Screenshot]

It would also be helpful if somecan can help me get the dock back to normal!

Note: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Any Help Would be Appreciated!

Comment: And if you restart the system does it still show up?

Comment: Did you manually install the official `Dash to Dock` GNOME Shell extension? You purged the official dock that's a part of 20.04. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and see if you can locate `Dash to Dock` and delete it there. Then reinstall the official dock.

Comment: Restarting gnome did work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Restarting gnome did not help for me. This did: dconf reset -f /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/

Comment: The dock in the activities overview is the default dock of Gnome. You can hide it using some extension. Just Perfection might work.

Comment: After I messed Dock with Dash-to-Dock (no icons at all) `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/` restored all my previous settings and icons. Ubuntu 22..04.2

Answer (score 0):

I just disengaged Dash to Dock with this link.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

It had a on\off switch and mine was on and I switched it to off.